# Can we overload MVC controller action methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

I was trying to overload controller method or action I am able to write controller action and compile but still I am not getting result.

```
   public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Contact(string str)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page by overloaded method";

        return View();
    }
```

but still I am getting following Error
**Server Error in '/' Application**

[image]

Comment: Because both are the [HttpGet] for the same action, you can overload with the same name only if the HTTP verbs are different, otherwise use a different name. The Action Name attribute will also be helpful as suggested by thangadurai

Comment: No you can't. But you can simulate it using ActionName attribute.

Answer (score 4):

You get the conflict because because `string` is nullable.

You can use `[ActionName("NewActionName")]` to give a different action name by leaving the method name intact.

You shouldn't get conflict if you have another action method like this

```
public ActionResult Contact(int Value)
```

But, below action will again fail

```
public ActionResult Contact(int? Value)
```

The reason is obvious. The parameter is again nullable.