# I Want to execute second Login(contactnumber,password) but after passing the argument it is still calling the list login method How to resolve this?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I Want to execute second Login(contactnumber,password) but after passing the argument it is still calling the list login method How to resolve this?

```
[HttpGet]
            public IEnumerable<UserDetail> Login()
            {
                using (HeandSheEntities entities = new HeandSheEntities())
                {
                    return entities.UserDetails.ToList();
                }
            }
            [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
            [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
            public HttpResponseMessage Login(String ContactNumber, String Password)    {
                {  String Upass = encryption(Password);
                    using (HeandSheEntities entities = new HeandSheEntities())
                    {
                        bool userphone = entities.UserDetails.Any(u => u.UserContactNumber.Equals(ContactNumber));
                        bool userpass = entities.UserDetails.Any(u => u.UserPassword.Equals(Upass));
                        if (ModelState.IsValid && userphone && userpass)
                        {
                           var user = entities.UserDetails.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserContactNumber.Equals(ContactNumber));
                            if (user != null)
                                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, user, new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
                            else
                                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Either Contact Number or password is not correct", new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Either Contact Number or password is not correct", new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        }
                        }
                    }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the same name for both action methods with the same http verb. You cannot overload action methods. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501852/can-we-overload-mvc-controller-action-methods). Semantically you should use POST http method for changing state (for example logging user) and it will work.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Login(String ContactNumber, String Password)
```

Comment: But when I am doing [HttpPost] It goes to some some post function.

Comment: public HttpResponseMessage Register([FromBody] UserDetail User)
        {
            //code}

Comment: Yes, and Post method is appropriate verb in this case.

Comment: I am not getting your solution Please explain